# IP multimedia subsystem cross compilation

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, powerpc, cross-compiling

I am using OpenIMSCore on x86 architecture. I need to cross compile OpenIMS for power-pc. In /ser_ims/Makefile.defs file there is a option for ppc. But I am not able to figure out how to cross compile it for ppc. There is no configure file through which I can configure IMS and compile it for ppc. Has anyone cross compiled IMS? I tried compiling through command

- make CFLAGS="arch=Power Macintosh"
- make CFLAGS="arch=ppc"

But both the commands are not working. It is giving following error:

> Makefile.defs:598: You are using an old and unsupported gcc version  (G++), compile at your own risk!
>   powerpc-linux-gnu-gcc -g -O9 -funroll-loops -Wcast-align -Wall     -DNAME='"ser"' -DVERSION='"2.1.0-dev1 OpenIMSCore"' -DARCH='"i386"' -DOS='linux_' -DOS_QUOTED='"linux"' -DCOMPILER='"powerpc-linux-gnu-gcc G++"' -D__CPU_i386 -D__OS_linux -DSER_VER=2001000 -DCFG_DIR='"/usr/local/etc/ser/"' -DPKG_MALLOC -DSHM_MEM  -DSHM_MMAP -DDNS_IP_HACK -DUSE_IPV6 -DUSE_MCAST -DUSE_TCP -DDISABLE_NAGLE -DHAVE_RESOLV_RES -DDBG_QM_MALLOC -DUSE_DNS_CACHE -DUSE_DNS_FAILOVER -DUSE_DST_BLACKLIST -ggdb  -DUSE_TLS -DTLS_HOOKS -DFAST_LOCK -DADAPTIVE_WAIT -DADAPTIVE_WAIT_LOOPS=1024  -DCC_GCC_LIKE_ASM -DHAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME2 -DHAVE_UNION_SEMUN -DHAVE_SCHED_YIELD -DHAVE_MSG_NOSIGNAL -DHAVE_MSGHDR_MSG_CONTROL -DHAVE_ALLOCA_H -DHAVE_TIMEGM -DHAVE_EPOLL -DHAVE_SIGIO_RT -DSIGINFO64_WORKARROUND -DHAVE_SELECT -c core_cmd.c -o core_cmd.o
>
> core_cmd.c: In function 'core_shmmem':
>   mem/../fastlock.h:181: error: can't find a register in class 'MQ_REGS' while reloading 'asm'
>   mem/../fastlock.h:358: error: can't find a register in class 'MQ_REGS' while reloading 'asm'
>   mem/../fastlock.h:181: error: can't find a register in class 'MQ_REGS' while reloading 'asm'
>   mem/../fastlock.h:181: error: 'asm' operand has impossible constraints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, the error you are getting is due to the separate header file definition and most importantly different shared library files for x86 architecture and different header files for PowerPC architecture. You can change the header file definitions with the new ones using "-I" flag and the shared library file path which is for PowerPC architecture, which can be changed by using -L option. But these all changes might be implemented in Makefile, so u just need to change the location in different flags, like LDFLAG, CFLAGS etc.

Comment: Now I am able to cross compile the IMS. After cross comiling I get the object files that are generated for power pc. But the problem now I am facing is that in OpenIMS there is not one Makefile. I have cross compiled through main Makefile that should effect all the other makefiles within IMS. But it is not doing so.

Comment: Yes, you will not get any error in generating object file, but at the linking stage of your cross compilation process as it will give errors related to architectural issues. That's what it will report that 'can't find a register in class'. I hope, somewhere in the makefile, you need to explicitly specify the different shared libraries path, to be specified in LDFLAG.